# Multiple authentication with Azure AD in web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

At once, there is one authentication option (Azure AD,Facebook,Twitter, google etc) can be configured in Azure web app.My need is to have multiple authentication for web app.User can select login options (Azure AD,Facebook,Twitter, google).

Is there any out of the box way in Azure Web app to configure multiple authentication option?

Answer (score -1):

If you create new ASP.Net MVC app, there should be options to do multiple authentication.

Azure Web App just host your application and doesn't set up any auth option. It also doesn't restrict you on how many auth option you could have. Auth options is defined and configure in your application.

See this tutorial for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on